# Error while loading data in BigQuery via command line : Updated

Tags: google-bigquery

Had ran a overnight job using a script.
It worked for lot of tables and then some 4 hrs back 7am IST approx started behaving weird
Now even single commands give the same error

```
bq load --max_bad_records=10 tbl163.a_V3_14Jun2012   a_V3_14Jun2012.log.gz ../schema/analyze.schema
```

Error:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Could not connect with BigQuery server, http
response status: 502
```

Update: I have received the following error just now

```
You have encountered a bug in the BigQuery CLI. Please send an email to bigquery-    team@google.com to report this, with the following information:

========================================
== Platform ==
CPython:2.7.3:Linux-3.2.0-25-virtual-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
== bq version ==
v2.0.6
== Command line ==
['/usr/local/bin/bq', 'load', '--max_bad_records=10', 'vizvrm299.analyze_VIZVRM299_26Jun2012', 'analyze_VIZVRM299_26Jun2012.log.gz', '../schema/analyze.schema']
== Error trace ==
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bq.py", line 614, in RunSafely
self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bq.py", line 791, in RunWithArgs
job = client.Load(table_reference, source, schema=schema, **opts)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 1473, in Load
upload_file=upload_file, **kwds)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 1228, in ExecuteJob
job_id=job_id)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 1214, in     RunJobSynchronously
upload_file=upload_file, job_id=job_id)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 1208, in StartJob
projectId=project_id).execute()
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bigquery_client.py", line 184, in execute
return super(BigqueryHttp, self).execute(**kwds)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/apiclient/http.py", line 644, in execute
_, body = self.next_chunk(http)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/apiclient/http.py", line 708, in next_chunk
raise ResumableUploadError("Failed to retrieve starting URI.")
========================================

Unexpected exception in load operation: Failed to retrieve starting URI.
```

Comment: In my case I saw this error message when I had a wrong schema. Instead of "integer" I had mentioned type as "int". This seems to be a bug since it is reporting wrong error.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close out this question, are you still observing these errors? This looks like a network configuration issue, not directly an issue with the bq command line tool. However, AFAIK, bq doesn't provide functions for resuming job insertion if there is a problem with the network.

Comment: How about the second error which says

You have encountered a bug in the BigQuery CLI. Please send an email to bigquery-    team@google.com to report this, with the following information: